# How can I fetch data from API

Tags: flutter

I have successfully create a API and Parsed it in a class Object but when I try to fetch the data inside my flutter application i get the error `nosuchmethoderror the method 'map' was called on null` I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong all the examples on google don't work

this is the output

```
 Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => Account)
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      new Wallet.fromJson (package:tronwallet/model/wallet.dart:23:48)
#2      walletFromJson (package:tronwallet/model/wallet.dart:7:45)
#3      _Dashboard.fetchData (package:tronwallet/dashboard.dart:44:31)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I tried to make some change but still the same error

```
import 'dart:convert';

Wallet walletFromJson(String str) => Wallet.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String walletToJson(Wallet data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Wallet {
  Wallet({
    this.seed,
    this.account,
  });

  String seed;
  List<Account> account;

  factory Wallet.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Wallet(
        seed: json["seed"],
        account:
            List<Account>.from(json["account"].map((x) => Account.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "seed": seed,
        "account": List<dynamic>.from(account.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Account {
  Account({
    this.privateKey,
    this.address,
  });

  String privateKey;
  String address;

  factory Account.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Account(
        privateKey: json["privateKey"],
        address: json["address"],
    );
  }
        
      

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['privateKey'] = this.privateKey;
        data['address'] = this.address;

        return data;
      }
  
  
  
  
  
}
```

What I tried to fetch the data

```
    bool isLoading = false;
  List<Account> list = [];
// override initState to run the _fetchData() function on state change
  fetchData() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    final response = await http.get('http://localhost:3000/list');

    

    // This is the above where you get the remote data
    // Like var response = await get or post

    final readResponseModel = walletFromJson(response.body);

    list = readResponseModel.account;

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }
```

the part I used to retrieve the data into my application

```
ListView.builder(
                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                      itemCount: list.length,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        return Card(
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Text(
                                                  '${list[index].address}'),
                                              Text('${list[index]}')
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the complete error code which should contains the line that breaks the program?

Simply judging from the way you are doing networking in your code is alright.

But I think there might be something else went wrong.

I suggest you post the whole project or just extract the part that break the program and make it a demo and post it on CodePen, if you want more helpful response.

Or you should add a null prevention to the place that use map such as this part:

```dart
  factory Wallet.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Wallet(
        seed: json["seed"],
        account:
            List<Account>.from(json["account"].map((x) => Account.fromJson(x))),
      );
```

can change to

```
  factory Wallet.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Wallet(
        seed: json["seed"],
        account: json["account"] == null ? null :
            List<Account>.from(json["account"].map((x) => Account.fromJson(x))),
      );
```

The bottom line is, when you are doing networking, there are chance that the networking will fail due to various reasons, such as wrong parameters or wrong api address, all of which will lead to a certain part of the response data is null or there's no such data response because the faulty input from the request.

So, you have to take these situation into account and add some null data prevention, like, what will the program will proceed if that data is null.

Comment: the fact is I have already generated item. it couldn't be null

Comment: I edit a few line but still have the error

Comment: @JosueGuessennd have you tried the null prevention method like I did in my post?

Comment: yes I tried to add the null prevention and it's not the result I wish @Benjamin Li